# ON DUPLICATE KEY insertS new record instead of updating with Unique key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a issue, my INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is inserting a new record instead of updating the row, the Table i am using has both an primary key and a unique key. So i am confused to why this is happening.

Table

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
`Product_Id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Resturant_ID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
`Product_Desc` text NOT NULL,
`Product_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Product_Price` decimal(8,0) NOT NULL,
`Add_On_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`Product_Id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `Product_Name` (`Product_Name`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

QUERY

```
   $add_product_errors = array();
    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $desc = $_POST['desc'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];
        $rest_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Resturant_ID']);
        if (empty($_POST['price']) || !filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || ($_POST['price'] <= 0)) {
            $add_product_errors['price'] = "Please enter a product price";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['item_name'])) {
            $add_product_errors['item_name'] = "Please enter a name";
        }
        if (empty($_POST['desc'])) {
            $add_product_errors['desc'] = "Please enter a product description";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO Product(Resturant_ID,Product_Name,Product_Desc,Product_Price) VALUES (?,?,?,?) 
            ON DUPLICATE KEY 
              UPDATE
              Resturant_ID = VALUES(Resturant_ID)
             ,Product_Name = VALUES(Product_Name)
             ,Product_Desc = VALUES(Product_Desc)
             ,Product_Price = VALUES(Product_Price)";
        $run_query = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
        if (!$run_query) {
            die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        }
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($run_query, 'sssd', $rest_id, $item_name, $desc, $price);
        $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($run_query);
        $item_name = strip_tags($_POST['item_name']);
        $desc = strip_tags($_POST['desc']);
        //100 - changes the way the decimal displays in database
        $price = strip_tags($_POST['price'] * 100);
        if ($execute) {
            echo "<script> alert('Addrrss Saved')</script>";
        } else {
            echo "<b>Oops! we have an issue </b>";
            mysqli_stmt_close($run_query);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You're not changing the values in your `ON UPDATE` - [see here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110781/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-not-working-as-i-expect). Also [give the mysql documentation for INSERT..ON DUPLICATE UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) a read-over: it recommendeds not to use `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE` it with more than 1 unique key. It may seem clean, but if you require Product Name to be unique, you are far better off handling this in your code. You can then load the duplicate product and show it to the user in a nice error message.

Comment: `Resturant_ID bigint(255) NOT NULL` this is too big, and will take up a disproportionate amount of time, ram and storage space. The number in brackets defines the *length* of the value not the actual value itself,so you're setting this number to being upto 255 digits long.  doubt you'd need more than 8, as a comparison, the [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is every second since 1970 is only 10 digits long.

Comment: @Martin because the website is built for a franchise, which has 90 franchises at the present moment, and is still growing i purposely made it 255, just to cover the companies growth. some of the franchises have over 50 restaurants each. But i do see what you mean

Comment: In MySQL the size for fields like `int`, `smallint` and `bigint` does *not* depend on the length value that's provided. A `bigint` uses 8 bytes, always, by definition. The length value is only important when you use `zerofill`, then the value will be left-padded with `0` to reach the specified length. (If more characters are needed, the number is still printed in full.) An `int` uses 4 bytes and can store numbers in exces of 4 billion (the column must be unsigned, but negative IDs don't make sense anyway. And `auto_increment` aways returns positive numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax just looks off to me.  Maybe try writing the SQL and testing it first in console or MySQL workbench or whatever first?  Try this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Product(Resturant_ID,Product_Name,Product_Desc,Product_Price) VALUES (?,?,?,?) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        Resturant_ID = ?
        ,Product_Name = ?
        ,Product_Desc = ?
        ,Product_Price = ?";

    $run_query = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
    if (!$run_query) {
        die(mysqli_error($dbc));
    }
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($run_query, 'issdissd', $rest_id, $item_name, $desc, $price, $rest_id, $item_name, $desc, $price);
```

<strike>Or maybe `?` eight times and binding things twice... not sure off hand if mysqli supports named parameters...</strike>

*Updated [again] per Martin's feedback.*

Comment: You're using PDO syntax when the OPs connection is a MySQLi connection.

Comment: Question marks are correct for mysqli prepared statements.

Comment: haha, nearly there - you need to extend the `sssd` to incorporate the repeated variables :-)

Comment: Updated :) now it looks like someone passed out on their keyboard.  I've now bothered to stop and look at [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) page. At least I learned something!

Comment: I give you a plus one for the effort, but hate to say it that `restaurant_ID` is an integer type and so the bind_param needs to be set as a `i`. :-D

Comment: Wish I had Martin to do peer reviews on my own code ;)

Comment: haha, I'm quite affordable for peer reviewing, except on Wednesdays, then I charge 2.5 x 10^4 :-)

Comment: @Martin the OP lists the restaurant id column as `Resturant_ID`. Probably a typo somewhere, but it's one of those that can be very annoying.

Comment: ficuscr got it right, (I was just doing some naff referencing )